¿Por qué mi gradiente CSS se repite en líneas verticales?
Un gradiente CSS se repite en líneas verticales en lugar de extenderse por todo el fondo de la página. He definido el gradiente en el cuerpo (<body>) de mi página web de la siguiente manera:
body {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(238,174,202);
    background: linear-gradient(5deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(42,54,69,1) 100%);
}


Como tu código es CSS, puedes agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica <>) para mostrar un [repro] ejecutable en esta pregunta del problema en cuestión. No olvides, por lo tanto, colocar también tu código HTML.



body {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(238,174,202);
    background: linear-gradient(5deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(42,54,69,1) 100%);
    height: 100vh;
}



Eso sucede porque tu elemento body no tiene una altura especificada ni tiene elementos dentro, por lo que su altura es la mínima. Esto genera que tu gradiente se replique multiples veces para completar el viewport. La solucion es darle una altura a body con "height", por ejemplo, prueba con "height: 100vh;".
